# Generar un gráfico de lineas con matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Con este sencillo script represento un gráfico de cotizaciones utilizando matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr 

AAPL = pdr.DataReader("AAPL", "yahoo", "2019-4-1", "2019-12-31")
df = AAPL[["Open","Close"]]

df.plot(figsize=(8,5))
plt.title("Cotizaciones de AAPL")
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para poder tener control sobre algunos parámetros del gráfico, elaboro este otro secript que me devuelve lo siguiente.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr 

AAPL = pdr.DataReader("AAPL", "yahoo", "2019-4-1", "2019-12-31")
df = AAPL[["Open","Close"]]
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5), tight_layout=True) 
plt.plot(df, "o-", linewidth=2) 
plt.xticks([2019, 2020])
plt.xlabel("Años")
plt.ylabel('Cotizaciones')
plt.title("Cotizaciones de AAPL")
plt.legend(title="AAPL", title_fontsize = 13, labels=["Open", "Close"])
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Qué error estoy cometiendo?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error en tu gráfico procede de la línea:

```
plt.xticks([2019, 2020])
```

ya que estás usando los enteros 2019 y 2020 como marcas para el eje X, pero ese eje contiene valores de tipo `datetime` y no de tipo `int`. El tipo `int` se está tomando como un contador de días, que se inicia el 1 de enero de 1970 (origen de tiempos Unix). Por tanto 2019 sería 2019 días después de ese inicio, lo que lleva al 13 de julio de 1975. Las dos únicas marcas que pones en tu eje de tiempos por tanto corresponden al 13 y 14 de julio de 1975. Ya que tus datos están en el año 2020, el eje X abarca unos 45 años y por tanto todo se ve "amontonado" en el año final.

Una solución simple es usar objetos `datetime` para marcar el eje X:

```
import datetime
plt.xticks([datetime.date(year=2019, month=1, day=1), 
            datetime.date(year=2020, month=1, day=1)])
```

[image: Grafica]

Puedes ser más preciso, ya que los datos empiezan en realidad en abril de 2020:

```
plt.xticks([datetime.date(year=2019, month=4, day=1), 
            datetime.date(year=2020, month=1, day=1)])
```

[image: Grafica 2]

### Bonus

Pero no necesitas "descender" al bajo nivel de matplotlib para tener control sobre tu gráfica. Cuando invocas `df.plot()` esta llamada te retorna un objeto de tipo "matplotlib axis", sobre el cual puedes hacer cualquier personalización que desees. Por ejemplo, podemos adaptar tu código para que quede así:

```
ax = df.plot(linewidth=2, style="o-", figsize=(8,5))
ax.set_xlabel("Años")
ax.set_ylabel('Cotizaciones')
ax.set_title("Cotizaciones de AAPL")
ax.legend(title="AAPL", title_fontsize = 13, labels=["Open", "Close"])
```

[image: Resultado]

Como ves el resultado es el mismo con la ventaja (?) de que en el eje X te salen automáticamente formateadas las fechas con su mes correspondiente (automáticamente pandas decide generar una marca cada mes, pero la "resolución" de las marcas depende del periodo de tiempo abarcado por el eje X completo, si fueran varios años pondría una marca por año, si fuera un solo mes pondría una marca por día, si fuera un solo día pondría una por hora, etc.)

Comment: ¡Qué importante es interiorizar el concepto "objetos" y darse cuenta que en Python todo son objetos.. Es mi próximo objetivo. Gracias.